# The risk of vim -Z (rvim)

Tags: ubuntu, vim, sudo, vimrc, sudoers

Last time I asked about the way to prevent risks caused by these configurations:

```
user_name ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf
```

or

```
%group_name ALL=(ALL) /usr/bin/vim /etc/httpd/confs/httpd.conf
```

If I write these scripts in /etc/sudoers, serious damage to the server can happen. Although the question was closed as primarily opinion-based, I received one opinion which recommended I use vim -Z.

I googled vim -Z and found some facts.
It is similar to (the same as?) rvim.
However, vim -Z still allows us to use some commands.
In order to prevent normal users from executing commands, we have to add several scripts in .vimrc.

To be honest, I do not understand fully what commands we cannot use in restricted mode. I found this website, but this only mentions vim although its title is rvim...
http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_rvim.htm

Could you tell me what settings are necessay to enable normal users to use sudo vim -Z (or sudo rvim) securely.

Comment: This really is outside the scope of this site.  It's better to only allow the use of `sudoedit`, which runs the editor as the normal user then only uses root power to replace the file with the new edited version.

Comment: To be clear, when you use `sudoedit`, you don't have to use `rvim`/`vim -Z` (the two are the same thing, just different ways of invoking it).

Comment: Which website should I use? Do you have any recommendation? I would like to know to build my knowledge even if it is not practical.

Comment: Although I don't frequent it, there's security.stackexchange.com. I don't know if your question would be appropriate there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you obsessed with `vim -V`? It's so criptic and difficult to handle its configuration. I don't see any advantage of `sudo vim -V` because it usually allows users to do more than you expect. It's much better to use `sudoedit`.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22084422/what-is-the-difference-between-sudoedit-and-sudo-vim
http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/